# jquery validate future date

Tags: jquery, validation, date

yet I didnt find a jquery function that validate value to be a future date ...
help please :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
function isFutureDate() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setFullYear(2020, 1, 1);
    var _now = new Date();
    if (date.getTime() > _now.getTime()) {
        // date is future
    }
}
```